# How to create epic that emits another one and at the same time listens for its end only once and until it fails?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I need to create Epic A, that will emit Action B, thus starting Epic B, which would make some async actions and emit Action C at the end, and at the same time Epic A sets up the listener for Action C and when it is received, it emits Action D, thus finishing listening for Action C, until called again.
Also...if Epic B returns Action E (fail case), then Epic A finished listening for Action C too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { mergeMap, map, take, takeUntil, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { merge, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

const smth = ($action, $state) =>
  $action.pipe(
    ofType('action-a'),
    withLatestFrom($state),
    mergeMap(([action, state]) => {
      const someData = someSelector(state);

      return merge(
        of({ type: 'action-b', someData }),
        $action.pipe(
          ofType('action-c'),
          map(() => {
            return {
              type: 'action-d',
            };
          }),
          take(1),
          takeUntil($action.pipe(ofType('action-e')))
        )
      );
    })
  );

export default smth;
```

In the code above we instantiate epic, that will run its contents when `action-a` is received.
It also returns one action and one listener (let's call it Sub-Epic).
Action is `action-b` and on completion, it will emit either action-c or action-e (fail case)
Sub-Epic itself listens for `action-c` to happen, we take it only once and take it until `action-e` is received because we want `action-d` to happen only once.

We run `action-d` as result of rerunning of `action-a`

To run that...we can just call `dispatch({ type: 'action-a' });`